# Load Test BindException

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, weblogic, load-testing

We have 2 APP's that one is server and other one is a client.

Server is on a weblogic (APP A) and client is on a spring-boot (on tomcat - APP B). When we are doing load test which A sends request to B. But after some point there are hundreads of Bind Exception errors for a time, than load test keep running normally, than Bind Exception, than normal etc.. If we do load test with higher TPS we get these exception more frequently. This is the scenario:

- Load test keep running, no error, 300 TPS, message count 10.000
- Load test keep running, no error, 300 TPS, message count 30.000
- Bind Exception, 300 TPS, mesasge count 32.000
- Load test keep running, no error, 300 TPS, message count 40.000
- Load test keep running, no error, 300 TPS, message count 50.000
- Bind Exception, 300 TPS, mesasge count 52.000
- Load test keep running, no error, 300 TPS, message count 60.000
  ...
  ...

Error is:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://XXXXXXX:9090/api/8252": Cannot assign requested address; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForLocation(RestTemplate.java:355)
        at com.ttech.tims.tes.pushws.impl.PushConsumerThread.tryToSendPushRequest(PushConsumerThread.java:207)
        at com.ttech.tims.tes.pushws.impl.PushConsumerThread.pushMessage(PushConsumerThread.java:162)
        at com.ttech.tims.tes.pushws.impl.PushConsumerThread.run(PushConsumerThread.java:350)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
       at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.newSocket(NIOSocketMuxer.java:432)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.newSocket(NIOSocketMuxer.java:364)
        at weblogic.socket.ChannelSocketFactory.createSocket(ChannelSocketFactory.java:98)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:384)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:511)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:313)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:292)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:295)
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
        ... 6 more
```

What i have tried so far:

- Increased clients max thread number (in application.properties from 100 to 500 etc.)
- Increased weblogics max concurrent thread count from 100 to 200 (300, 400 etc.) via console
- Checked max open files for server and client.
- Checked firewall between server and client.
- Monitored with Java Mission Control and checked for Thread Blocking status. Threads are blocked because of log4j writing errors with 300TPS when exception occures. But this doesn't solve the problem why we have those exceptions. Decraesed log level from Info to Error.

No improvements so far, still getting BindExceptions after some point. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are running out of client ports. Either you are leaking sockets or else you are just creating them too quickly. Do you have lots of ports in TIME_WAIT state?

Comment: Yes you are right, it looks like that i have some problems with connections. When i type this command: netstat -an | grep 9090 (server's port) , on the client side i see 100.000 connections and most of them is ESTABLISHED state. On the client side all of those connections are in the TIME_WAIT state. I use RestTemplate of Spring. I don't create new rest template for each connections, I injected it to the bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks EJP for suggestions. Here is how i solve the problem. Spring Rest template is waiting for unix to close the connections. For this reason after i reach the maximum socket connections, connections wait in TIME_WAIT state. When we send Apache ClientHttpRequestFactory as a factory for spring RestTemplate, than apache handles requests with its connection pool. Here is the implementation:

```js
    @Bean("apacheRequestFactory")
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory() {

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

        // maximum connections in the pool
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(this.systemPropertyBean.getPushConsumerThreadCnt());

        // maximum concurrent connection to the hosts is equal to the our push thread count.
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(this.systemPropertyBean.getPushConsumerThreadCnt());

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(this.systemPropertyBean.getPushTimeoutMillis())// 3 sn
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(this.systemPropertyBean.getPushTimeoutMillis())
                .setSocketTimeout(this.systemPropertyBean.getPushTimeoutMillis()).build(); // read timeout

/*      the Connection Timeout (http.connection.timeout) – the time to establish the connection with the remote host
        the Socket Timeout (http.socket.timeout) – the time waiting for data – after the connection was established; maximum time of inactivity between two data packets
        the Connection Manager Timeout (http.connection-manager.timeout) – the time to wait for a connection from the connection manager/pool
*/        
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
// I was using SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory before.
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(createRequestFactory());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        return restTemplate;
    }
```